# Validation with cleaned_data()

Tags: django

I'd like to ask you if you can briefly and in plain English explain to me
how `cleaned_data()` function validates data ?

Reason for asking is that I'm designing a web app powered by Django
and initially I thought `cleaned_data()` is smart enough to block user's input that contains potentially harmful characters. Such as `' ; < >` and alike. Characters that can be used for SQL injection attacks.
To my surprise, when I deliberately slipped few of those characters into form field, the input made it to database. I was quite shocked.

So then ... what the `cleaned_data()` function is good for ?

I read about this function in docs, however I couldn't find necessarily answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cleaned_data` is for [validated form data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/). If you have a required CharField, for example, it will validate whether it is present, and whether it has enough characters. If you have an EmailField, then it will validate that it includes an email address.

[Take a look at some of the build in form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/) for a better idea of what you can do.

It is not intended to prevent XSS or SQL injection. It simply confirms that your form follows basic rules that you have set for it.

Comment: Sweet ... simple, concise and straight to the point answer. Thumb's up !

Comment: At least I now know I need to make my own validation and sanitize the input.

Answer (score 0):

You missunderstood `cleaned_data`. The simplest definition of `cleaned_data` is something like:

> A dict that contains data entered by the user after various validation
>   (built-in or custom)

Now, that being said, to understand every steps to form validation refer to this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) (re-inventing the wheel would be silly since it is greatly explained.)

As for the SQL injection, this is another problem. But again, Django as a built-in way of handling it, this is from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection):

> By using Django’s querysets, the resulting SQL will be properly
>   escaped by the underlying database driver. However, Django also gives
>   developers power to write raw queries or execute custom sql. These
>   capabilities should be used sparingly and you should always be careful
>   to properly escape any parameters that the user can control. In
>   addition, you should exercise caution when using extra() and RawSQL..

I can totally see your confusion, but remember that they are two different things.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. Yes I learned from documentation that this is a dictionary-based function. I just misunderstood how it actually works. As mentioned above I thought it's designed to sanitize malicious input.